# How to display the changed id values using jquery ready function in page view source

Tags: jquery

I am using jsp and jquery and the below method to replace the unique ids seen in a page.

But while inspecting the pages the ids are getting replaced but in the view page source still the old values are displayed.

Can anyone help on how to get the changed id values in page source as well.

Please find the code snippet for changing the id values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('[id]').each(function () {
    var ids = $('[id="' + this.id + '"]');
    if (ids.length > 1 && ids[0] == this) {
        for (i = 1; i < ids.length; i++) {
            $(ids[i]).attr('id', this.id + '_' + i);
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You can't. You are delivering the page with the original IDs and let the client change them. The original IDs are in the original source cause that is what was delivered. If you do not want to deliver the Original IDs, you have to change them on the server before delivering the source.

Comment: You can't do this - but don't worry because there's no need to do this. View page source just shows the original state of the page when it was loaded from the server. It's not useful for anything else. Nothing depends on its contents after that moment. If you adjust JS variables and HTML elements during the life of the page it works fine regardless of the original state. Why were you thinking you would need to do this?

Comment: Also...why do you want to replace unique element IDs? The whole purpose of them is to be unique and immutable during the life of the page. This entire thing does not make much sense.

Comment: ADyson -  It was a typo , i need to have unique ids. The code i have given is to replace the duplicate ids only.

Comment: Would it not be better if the server was not creating HTML containing duplicate IDs in the first place? This code is just a sticking-plaster covering broken server code.

Comment: Yes, but there are some third party server codes has been used, so we are not having control over the service side.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $('[id]').each(function(){
        i++;
        this.id = this.id + '_' + i;
    });
});
```

Worked for me in Chromium Dev Tools Elements.

Comment: The same code is working for me too , but the issue is in view page source still the old ids are seen.
This is for testing the site in AODA compatibility.

Comment: You issue is that you are looking at the code that was used only to build the DOM. After you change the DOM, the source code that you downloaded from the server stays the same. Ids are changed only in the DOM, and you can see those changes in your DevTools.

Comment: Thanks for clarity Michael